# Prove that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is defined if and only if $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I feel as though there is probably a simpler way, although I'm happy I completed the proof, even if I made some mistakes.

What is the intended proof, and is my proof correct?

---

> $a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$. $(a,b)$ is the notation for the greatest common divisor.
>
> Show that $(a,b)$ is defined iff $a,b$ are not both $0$.

Restatement: $\exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)\Leftrightarrow a\neq 0 \vee b\neq 0$

Left to right side: $\exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)\to a\neq 0 \vee b\neq 0$

Proof strategy: Proof by contradiction of the contrapositive.

Contrapositive: $a=0 \wedge b=0 \to \forall x\exists y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b \wedge |y|>|x|)$

Assume $p \wedge \neg q$: $(a=0 \wedge b=0) \wedge \exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)$

We'll show that for any divisor, there is a greater divisor.

Let $c \in \mathbb{Z}\;st\;c\;|\;a,b$

Since $a=b=0$, then $c\;|\;0,\;2c\;|\;0$, and then

$\forall c(c\;|\;a,b \wedge 2c\;|\;a,b \wedge |c| < |2c|)$

Set $x = c$, $y=2c$

This contradicts our assumption $\exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)$ since

$c\;|\;a,b \wedge 2c\;|\;a,b\;\;$ but $\;\;|c| \ngeq |2c|$

So by contradiction we have proven the contrapositive $a=0 \wedge b=0 \to \forall x\exists y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b \wedge |y|>|x|)$

And also the original implication $\exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)\to a\neq 0 \vee b\neq 0$

Right to left side: $a\neq 0 \vee b\neq 0 \to \exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)$

Proof strategy: Proof by contradiction.

Assume $p \wedge \neg q$: $(a \neq 0 \vee b \neq 0) \wedge \forall x\exists y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b \wedge |y|>|x|)$

We'll show that there is no greater divisor than $ab$.

Let $c=ab$

Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}\;st\;|d| > |c|$

$\forall d(d\nmid c) \therefore \forall d(d \nmid ab) \therefore \forall d(d \nmid a \vee d \nmid b)$

Set $x = c$, $y = d$

This contradicts our assumption $\forall x\exists y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b \wedge |y|>|x|)$ since

$|d| > |c| \to d\;\nmid\;a \vee d\;\nmid\;b$

So by contradiction we have proven $a\neq 0 \vee b\neq 0 \to \exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)$

We've proven both sides of $\exists x\forall y(x\;|\;a,b \wedge y\;|\;a,b\to|x|\geq|y|)\Leftrightarrow a\neq 0 \vee b\neq 0$,

So we have shown that $(a,b)$ is defined iff $a$ and $b$ are not both 0.

Comment: What's your definition of $(a,b)$? Also, are $a,b$ integers here?

Comment: You can post LaTeX here directly.

Comment: @Wojowu $(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a,b$. Sorry, that is the standard notation used in my textbook, did not realize it was uncommon. Yes, $a,b$ are non-zero integers.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=b=0$, then every member of $\mathbb Z$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and thus there is no greatest common divisor.

Inversely, assume that either $a$ or $b$ is non-zero.  Without loss of generality, assume $|a|>|b|$.   Then the set $S$ of common factors of $a$ and $b$ is nonempty, since $1\in S$.  Also, no integer greater than $|a|$ can be a divisor of $a$, so $S$ is bounded above.  Therefore, $S$ has a maximum member, which is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

I'm having a lot of trouble following your proof.  I have a sense that it's [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong), but you might want someone else to verify that.

Comment: I really like the second part of the proof you give. I'm taking number theory and real analysis concurrently, and we just used that style to prove the Well Ordering Property from the Strong Induction Principle in real analysis. Seeing the crossover is beautiful.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to rewrite this proof using rigorous mathematical definitions, and rigorous proof methods (direct proof / proof by contradiction / direct proof of contrapositive / proof by contradiction of contrapositive)?

Comment: @okovko I would think so.  You'd want a lemma (if you don't already have one) that a non-empty set of integers that is bounded above has a maximum member (which is just essentially a rehash of the well-ordering principle proof).  Then maybe split your proof into three parts: $(0,0)$ is undefined, $(a,0)=|a|$, and $(a,b)>|ab|$ followed by the maximum value argument.

Comment: If you have time and you're willing, I just rewrote my proof much more explicitly and wrote the latex in the browser as well. Maybe now you can more readily determine the correctness?

Answer (score 0):

Three lines:

$k*0 = 0$ for every possible $k \in \mathbb N$ so every natural natural number is a divisor of $0$ and every natural number (of which there is no greatest) is a common divisor of $a=0$ and $b=0$.

If $b\ne 0$ then $b$ divides $0$ so $\gcd(0,b) = |b|$.

If $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$ then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(|a|,|b|)$ which Euclid's Algorithm assures us exists.

Comment: Assuming the definition of gcd to prove this is not satisfactory. I'd be more interested if you proved it using my definition ∃x∀y(x|a,b∧y|a,b→|x|≥|y|) or with a valid definition of your own.